# How to retain old value for a name like name="custom[test]" on input in laravel ? suppose

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-6

I want to show the old value after validation fails in laravel. I have seen for errors like `test.0` or `test.1` and so on... But let say I have 20 inputs and i have used those inputs for mass assignment like this `name="custom[name1]",name="custom[name2]"` and so on... and I am just passing `custom` to the Eloquent model and it works fine, all the inputs are inserted successfully! But in case if validation fails then how to retain the old value of the specific input for this scenario.

e.g

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_address[city]" value="{{ old('company_address.city') }}">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_address[zip]" value="{{ old('company_address.zip') }}">
```

in controller validation is something like this....

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
   'company_address.city' => 'required',
   'company_address.zip'  => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
      return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

The error is showing like this ...

```
The company address.city is required. 
The company address.zip is required.
```

The validation is working fine, but it is not showing the input old value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure, does your route have the `web` middleware assigned to it? You can check this easily with `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: yeah it is assigned by default.

Comment: I have 4 middlewares assigned to it including web.

Comment: have you tried `old("company_address[city]")`?

Comment: seems to be working for me

Comment: Yes, i have tried this way as well. but doesn't work.

Comment: @lagbox bad luck for me, its not working

Comment: i guess this isn't the code you actually have, but those 2 fields are 'required' and they are failing, so what old value are you expecting?   i would `dump(old())` in the controller method returning your view and see what you have

Comment: @lagbox hmm, you have a point, let me check some extra validation on it, I think this might be my silly mistake.

Comment: @lagbox Exactly, that was my silly mistake, ugh! Thanks for this point.